# Running Laravel Artisan Schedule with prefix

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, symfony-console

I am running an artisan command via the scheduler on elastic beanstalk.

Elastic beanstalk cronjobs need to be passed the environment variables required for the process as follows.

```
* * * * * ec2-user source /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars; php /var/app/current/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Where `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars` is a list of exports.

This works fine for the process running the scheduler itself, but the scheduler executes commands on separate processes and therefore the environment variables are missing.

For example

```
[ec2-user@ip-x-x-x-x current]$ php artisan schedule:run
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php-7.0' 'artisan' rewards:notify > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

Which then doesn't have access to the environment variables because the shell doesn't have a concept of a profile it seems and therefore doesn't autosource `.bashrc` etc.

How can I get the environment variables from the aforementioned file to be read in before my commands?

Comment: Could you parse /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars before execution in your command classes and set the variables using putenv()? There's a slightly messy example of that in one of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563862/aws-elastic-beanstalk-running-cron-d-script-missing-environment-variables